# Save android value and retrieve it again

Tags: java, android

I have the following void

```
protected void onPaymentSuccess(PaymentResponse response) {
  // Stuff...
}
```

I want to save a string within a void for example

```
String key = "JHIJHFEIRUFHEURFGEU5";
```

And i want to be able to retrieve it again (this string to be saved to phone) after phone restart, closing application.

Comment: *i want to save a string within a void* -- Hehe :-)

Comment: You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to persist and load data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) will show you many techniques you can use to save thing in a persistant manner so that the can be retrieved even after your application has closed / the device has been turned off etc...

Which one of the proposed ways you want to use depends on what exactly you need. You haven't given many details about your situation so I wouldn't know which will work best for you.

Answer (score 5):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) inside your application. This allows you to save persistent data and retrive it using a key that you specify. Use [Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) to modify the values.

Comment: As a possible second solution, a Database could be used.

Comment: could you gimme an example how to save it and how to retrieve it using SharedPrefernces ? Thank YOU